# MySQL PHP: Extra Rows

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL the table `test` looks like this:

```
id  name         lft      rgt
1   Folder 1        1          10
2   Child 1         2           3
3   Child 2         4           7
4   Child 1         5           6
5   Child 3         8           9
```

When I do:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELETCT * FROM test ORDER BY id");
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($results);

echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($fetch);
echo "</pre>;
```

The result is:

```
[0] => 1
[id] => 1
[1] => Folder 1
[name] => Folder 1
[2] => 1
[lft] => 1
[3] => 10
[rgt] => 10
```

My question is why `[0] => 1`, `[1] => Folder 1`, `2] => 1` and `[3] => 10` are there? As I see they are somehow linked with the original rows, maybe these are the indexes for them but how should I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) has three modes of retrieving data. The default is `MYSQL_BOTH`, which is what you're seeing - a combo hash+array structure. The other two modes are array-only (`MYSQL_NUM`) and hash-only (`MYSQL_ASSOC`).

In other words, these are direct 1:1 correspondence in fetch modes:

```
mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM) === mysql_fetch_row($results)
mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC) === mysql_fetch_assoc($results)
mysql_fetch_array($results)  === mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_BOTH) // default mode.
```

Answer (score 3):

That's how mysql_fetch_array works: you can use an index from 0 to 3, or you can use the name.

If you only want to use the name you can use: mysql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 0):

The command mysql_fetch_array will fetch you both an associative and a numeric array unless you specify which one you want.
Instead, try using:

```
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
```